# iPhone app- preforming navigation externally with Waze

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, launch

I need to implement the following flow in my application:
the user can click on a certain destination and by doing so my iPone app should launch waze which would navigate to that point.

What is the simplest way to do that?

Thanks,Asaf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to communicate with other iOS apps is by launching them using a URL scheme the apps developer configured. you should check and see if waze provides a URL scheme and use it with `-openURL:` method of `UIApplication`

here is an example of using the system preferences URL scheme to open the iPhone location settings on iOS 5

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
```

Comment: apparently the solution is very simple: NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"waze://?ll=%@,%@&navigate=yes",self.lat,self.lon]; Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for open Waze map application for navigation using swift 3

```
let urlStr = "waze://?ll=\(Destination Latitude),\(Destination Longitude)&navigate=yes"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
```